# How to get totalspace and freespace in java1.5?

Tags: java, java-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find how much disk space is left using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051295/how-to-find-how-much-disk-space-is-left-using-java)

Can somebody tell me how to get freespace and totalspace on java 1.5? I know there is API for java 1.6, getTotalSpace and getFreeSpace, but I really need to get it done on 1.5, thanks for any pointers!

Comment: The 2nd highest scoring answer of the linked question is for older Java releases ...

Comment: For anyone who finds this in the future and notices that the linked answers don't include a way to get the **total space**, here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130660/portable-way-of-finding-total-disk-size-in-java-pre-java-6